# Java 8 map filter and sort

Tags: java, dictionary, filter, java-8, java-stream

I want to migrate this example to Java 8:

```
Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("name", "Middle");
    put("prefix", "Front");
    put("postfix", "Back");
}};

    String title = "";
    if (data.containsKey("prefix")) {
    title += data.get("prefix");
}

if (data.containsKey("name")) {
    title += data.get("name");
}

if (data.containsKey("postfix")) {
    title += data.get("postfix");
}
```

Correct output:

```
FrontMiddleBack
```

I tried with entryset -> stream but it doesn't return in correct order.

```
String titles = macroParams.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(map -> "name".equals(map.getKey()) || "postfix".equals(map.getKey()) || "prefix".equals(map.getKey()))
        .sorted()
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Output:

```
MidleFrontBack
```

Can I get the same result using Java 8?

Comment: Your original code is broken. `concat()` doesn't modify the string it's called on.

Comment: `HashMap` is unordered. If you want to preserve ordering, use a `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: *I tried to migrate to java 8.* Java 8 is backwards compatible. You don't have to change every (or any) line of code just because you updated Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can stream over the desired keys and join values that are present:

```
String title = Stream.of("prefix", "name", "postfix")
        .filter(data::containsKey)
        .map(data::get)
        .collect(joining());
```

Comment: Very nice. You can avoid an extra lookup by filtering null after `get()`.

Answer (score 9):

Streams are a little overkill here, IMO. But you can still use Java 8 to your advantage, with [`Map.getOrDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-):

```
String title = data.getOrDefault("prefix", "")
        + data.getOrDefault("name", "")
        + data.getOrDefault("postfix", "");
```